# Centring a heading, including the numbering

Tags: sectioning, horizontal-alignment, titlesec

I've got a problem that should be simple to fix. I'm using the fontspec to layout my chapter headings like so

```
%!TEX TS-program = xelatex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[oneside,a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{25}{30}\bfseries\centering \fontspec{Times New Roman}}}
  {\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:\space }{0pt}
  {}[]
   \begin{document}
   \chapter{The Road In The Wood}

   \end{document}
```

and for the most part it works just as I want. There is however one slight issue, some of my chapter headings run onto two lines - that's fine. However instead of centring the the second line properly it's placed towards the right of the page.

I believe what it's doing is centring as though the page begins just after the "Chapter 1" part of the heading. Is there a way to tell it to center based on the whole page?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please expand your code to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), with a document class, (only!) all the necessary packages, etc.

Comment: All done. +charlimit

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, I can't help you with your problem, but I'm sure someone who can will come along soon. However, I do think you've got an erroneous brace in your code, sc. after `Times New Roman`; you only need two closing braces there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've succeeded with

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]
  {\normalfont\fontsize{25}{30}\bfseries\fontspec{Times New Roman}}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {\centering\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter:\space}
```

However I wouldn't use `\fontspec`, but rather

```
\newfontfamily{\timesnr}[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
```

and `\timesnr` instead of `\fontspec{Times New Roman}`

*Never* use the `inputenc` package with XeLaTeX.